# View all my Facebook fans similar to "Social Graph" app

Tags: facebook

[Social Graph](http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=67692068407) is a Facebook app that lets you view your friends, grouped by their interactions. Is there something similar for Fan Pages? I would like to know how my fans are grouped (I have 41 Fans at the moment, so scale is not a problem)

Comment: Great question, thanks! I did some digging but to no avail. Seems all the available tools only take work with friends.

Answer (score 2):

Have you read through the developer section on Facebook? This might be of use to you: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Answer (score 0):

This might be something to check out:
http://www.readwriteweb.com/archives/nexus_graphs_your_facebook_friends.php

Comment: From the post you linked it I don't see that it supports Fan pages...